# asp.net MVC 4.0 membership database

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, asp.net-membership

I'm familiar with aspnet_regsql.exe to create a membership database in asp.net web forms. but i am not aware about MVC4.0(visual studio 2012) membership. what should i do to have these membership table in SQL server management studio 2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tables are created automatically the first time you try to register a user.  If you want to configure a remote database, then you can use database migrations to generate a script to execute to create the tables afterwards.

Comment: I know tables are automatically created. but i want to access those tables via SQL server management studio not from visual studio server explorer Data connection

Comment: @juhi - I don't think you quite understand what you're asking for.  There is no difference between SSMS and database connection accessing the tables of a remote database.

Comment: @juhi - If you mean you don't want to use a localdb instance, then you do as I said above and generate a database migrations script to run against your remote database.  Then you point your connection string to that database.